# Receiving Stack Overflow emails again, despite opting out

Tags: bug, email

Since 12th May 2023, so four days, I suddenly got promotional or research e-mails (offering me 30 dollars for something and a few days later asking me to complete the developer survey) from Stack Overflow. I went to my profile and under Settings -> Edit Email settings the "promotional" email was checked. Now, I cannot be sure, but am fairly certain I disabled that the moment I created my account. I haven't gotten promotional email at any point in the past.

Why has this option suddenly been enabled? Was this intentional (and as such in violation of the GDPR)? All other settings for emails were switched off, as I set them.

E-Mail headers:

```
1:
from:   Lizzie at Stack Overflow <research@stackoverflow.email>
reply-to:   efalcone@stackoverflow.com
to: ---
date:   12 May 2023, 18:16
subject:    Share feedback about Stack Overflow ($30 for 30 min)
mailed-by:  em.stackoverflow.email
Signed by:  stackoverflow.email
unsubscribe:    Unsubscribe from this sender
security:   Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more

2:
from:   Stack Overflow <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email>
reply-to:   do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email
to: ---
date:   16 May 2023, 10:05
subject:    2023 Dev Survey: Are you using AI tools in your workflow?
mailed-by:  em.stackoverflow.email
Signed by:  stackoverflow.email
unsubscribe:    Unsubscribe from this sender
security:   Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more
```

Comment: the 30-dollar "something" is likely not a promotional email but an invitation to a research session with an SE employee if you have the "Settings -> Edit Email Settings -> Research -> Invitations" setting enabled.

Comment: Same goes for the developer survey - I doubt it is considered a part of "business-related emails to promote our paid products to potential business customers".

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine that one's turned off and I didn't have to disable that again. So that's an incorrect email for sure.

Comment: If you got a research invitation email when the option is turned off, that's... peculiar. Just noting that the emails are unlikely to be considered promotional by SE, however, I agree this is odd to get them if you have both options disabled (and to get the Promotional section option enabled if you explicitly remember it being disabled before).

Comment: Looks like my scam works. The sender is *letsseeifadriaangetstrickedbythis@gmail.com*, right?

Comment: Just ruling out I am scamming you, mind sharing the mail headers? Do anonymize them as they might contain PII.

Comment: @rene if at least you'd offer me a useful currency, rather than that overseas monopoly money ;)

Comment: Can confirm the email is a research email commonly used for invitations for a research session - meaning that there might be a bug with respecting user preferences for opting out of invitations to such sessions.

Comment: Did you sign-up for a new site recently?

Comment: @rene I don't think so. Also, shouldn't that enable emails on that site, rather than SO? I apparently joined [history.se] 4 months ago, the other SE sites I have an account on, I joined more than a year ago

Comment: It shouldn't matter but I assume you're right that you didn't change that option and I try to think about use cases that might interfere with your profile. Account creation (and syncing) might be such case, hence my comment.

Comment: Are you sure it said dollars and not 30U̶ (Unicoins)? Since that's the established SO cryptocurrency.

Comment: Hey @Adriaan, I'm one of the UX Researchers at Stack Overflow. Thanks for raising this issue! Will be sharing back with my team to check what might have happened. As Oleg suggested, there might be a bug with respecting user preferences, so will look into that. We would be exceptionally happy to have you participate in research sessions with us, but of course we want to respect your preferences.

Comment: @EmmaBee a month later, any updates about why the email has been sent against user preferences?

Comment: Sorry to not get back to you about this. I did some digging, but could not find an issue. @Adriaan if your email settings are set as you prefer and it happens again, please email me directly and will look more into it!