# How do I save my Stack Overflow email settings?

Tags: bug, status-review, profile-page, email

When I attempt to unsubscribe from the spam emails I receive from Stack Overflow I'm required to log in and update my email settings. When I update them, the changes don't save. Even when I click the save button on the email address (which I would think only saved the address and not the rest but it was worth trying). What step am I missing?

Initially I expected it to simply apply the changes immediately on toggling the setting and not require any manual save. On refreshing, the settings were reenabled and so I have searched the Email Settings page for a Save button of some sort and found only the save button for the Email Address field. I have tried toggling the subscription settings all to off and pressing that, to no avail. Every time I refresh the page they're toggled back on.

Looking at the console history of the page it had apparently been giving a 403 error. Is there a reputation requirement in order to even unsubscribe? Apparently posting this question triggered something in the backend because after posting it now saves as I initially expected - automatically. So if, like me, you're searching for how to unsubscribe and receiving a 403, try posting something.

Comment: Per your last paragraph, I created a new account and didn't post anything, but I wasn't able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Potentially related: [Receiving Stack Overflow emails again, despite opting out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424730/15497888)